# Node JS readFileSync Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode

Tags: node.js, utf-8, fs

I want read a text file in node js

This is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const contents = fs.readFileSync('1.txt', 'utf8');
console.log(contents);
```

But i got this error:

```
(node:5168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): SyntaxError: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode.
(node:5168) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

At this point, how can I read a text file?

Answer (score 0):

The program works well
The problem was in the name of the file I had written badly